# Does SECTION run at the same time in Unit testing C++(catch2)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch2

I am new to C++ and I am learning Unit testing using catch2. I am writing a testcase like this

```
TEST_CASE("Sandwich::AddTopping test", "[AddTopping]") {
  // your tests for Sandwich::AddTopping here
  Sandwich newsandwich;

  SECTION("adding two cheese") {
    newsandwich.AddTopping("cheese");
    REQUIRE(newsandwich.AddTopping("cheese") == false);
  }

  SECTION("adding more than 5 toppings") {
    newsandwich.AddTopping("cheese");
    newsandwich.AddTopping("lettuce");
    newsandwich.AddTopping("tomato");
    newsandwich.AddTopping("onions");
    newsandwich.AddTopping("pickles");
    REQUIRE(newsandwich.AddTopping("cheese") == false);
  }

  SECTION("adding 2 other toppings") {
    newsandwich.AddTopping("lettuce");
    REQUIRE(newsandwich.AddTopping("lettuce"));
  }

  SECTION("adding in range") { REQUIRE(newsandwich.AddTopping("lettuce")); }
}
```

However, my code only create one Sandwich object at the beginning but the output of this is the same as teh one when I create objects separately for each SECTION. Can someone tell me why? Thank you~

Comment: why `add cheese => false` but `add lettuce => true`?

Comment: So the question says toppings cannot have two cheeses but other toppings are fine.